# Sonicwall tz210 configuration issues

Tags: vpn, router, sonicwall

I recently upgraded my firmware on my tz210w (maybe a month ago).  Ever since I have been having issues logging into the administrator configuration via browser.  Has anyone else noticed this issue?
The only fix I have found is to restart the router manually.  This is obviously problematic when I want to make changes remotely (out of office).

Comment: Noticed the same problem on our NSA2400 since our last firmware upgrade.

Comment: Not sure if they have released a new firmware on your model but I found this on the sonicwall forums.  https://forum.sonicwall.com/showthread.php?t=24157&page=2&highlight=tz210  It is a known issue and they released an update for the tz210 to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the firmware to one that was released a week ago.  I am now running 5.5.2.1-5o.  I haven't experienced a problem.